# How to implement conditional logic in html?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json, forms

I am trying to ensure that part II of the HTML page is executed only after I have successfully submitted the required information through the form.

This problem is part of a Flask application. I am trying to run *Part II* only after *Part I*, because otherwise I would have a python stream webcan function running automatically.

```
<!--Part I -->

<form id="form" action="{{ url_for("index")}}" method="post">

     <div class="row" >
        <div class="col s4">
            <label class="name-info" for="txtName">Name:</label>
            <input name="host" id="txtName" />
        </div>

        <div class="col s4">
            <label class="age-info" for="txtAge">Age:</label>
            <input name="port" id="txtAge" />
        </div>      
    </div>
</form>
```

```
<!--Part II -->

<div class="container">
    <div class="col-lg-8">
        <img src="{{ url_for('video_feed') }}">
     </div>
</div>
```

How do I create an if condition inside an HTML page that becomes true when the button is clicked?

Comment: `{% if cond1==cond2 %}` is python? Where are those variables set? Please include all relevant code.

Comment: Seems like you tagged the question with everything but the templating language that you're actually using.

Comment: I didn't put the code in python because it wouldn't be relevant to the problem. I will edit the question to make it clearer.

Comment: Can you check to see if the form/POST variable(s) exist? If they do, show part 2.

Comment: These variables were a test I did, for example, I was pasting a negation to see if the code would work the way I wanted it to. And it did.

The problem is that I could not get these variables, for example, I tried to use fetch to read my json file, but could not succeed.

Comment: @user1599011 If somehow some *if condition* is created that makes true when the button is clicked. My problem is solved.

Comment: I'm not understanding what your JSON file has to do with this html and form. If you're submitting the form, you should be able to retrieve its variables and use them. I don't know python or Flask, but in Coldfusion, for example, you can use something like `if (structKeyExists(form,"host")){doStuff();}`

Comment: The JSON is essential for my code, because I will use the values that the user submits in another part of the code that is written in python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what the business logic should be and if it should be on backend or frontend.

Based on your question, I assume the following: You have a form (part 1) and you want to display the rest of your code (part 2) only when the form has been submitted with the required data. If so, this may help:

```js
document.getElementById('form').addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (document.getElementById('txtName').value.length > 0 && document.getElementById('txtAge').value.length > 0) {
    document.querySelector('.container').removeAttribute('hidden');
  }
});
```

```html
<!--Part I -->

<form id="form" action='{{ url_for("index")}}' method="post">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col s4">
      <label class="name-info" for="txtName">Name:</label>
      <input name="host" id="txtName" />
    </div>

    <div class="col s4">
      <label class="age-info" for="txtAge">Age:</label>
      <input name="port" id="txtAge" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<!--Part II -->

<div class="container" hidden>
  <div class="col-lg-8">
    <img src="{{ url_for('video_feed') }}">
  </div>
</div>
```

This checks whether the input fields contain values. Since this is only for the frontend, you will have security issues if you do not validate the data in the backend as well.

You also have security issues if you place your "secret" code directly in DOM, even if it is hidden. If it is secret, you should retrieve the data from your server whenever it is needed.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend using Django to integrate your python code seamlessly with HTML forms.

You can achieve this using HTML + Javascript, here's an example:

```
<button onclick="submitForm()">Submit</button>

<div id="myDIV">
  This is my DIV element.
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function submitForm() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```